# Is there a SQL function statement which returns an array within limits and replaces digits with * to reduce the size

Tags: sql, arrays, function, arguments

Need to write a sql function that takes two different integers with the same length (same amount of digits) as arguments: one lower threshold and one upper threshold. 
And the function should return a vector with all whole numbers between the two thresholds - but to reduce the array length, your function is supposed to return a wildcard character instead of the digits where possible.

Example: output of the function for a lower threshold L = 3778 and an upper threshold U = 9423
To further clarify, the line in the example showing 941* has one digit replaced by the wild card character and hence represents all values from 9410 - 9419
The line in the example showing 93* has two digits replaced by the wildcard character and represents all values from 9300 - 9399
And so on.

```
9423
9422
9421
9420
941*
93*
.
378*
3779
3778
```

Comment: (1) Arrays are not really a SQL datatype, although some databases support them.  That makes (2) a database tag very important.  (3) Vectors are not a SQL datatype in any database, as far as I know.  See (2).  This type of operation is not really something  you would normally do in a database.

Comment: Can R language be used for this.? If yes, any guidance on that